# Meta tags on meta?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

This site is full of meta tags. Now the [meta tags are discouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), how will things work here?

The meta tags I am talking about are:

- feature-request
- discussion
- support
- bug
- status-XXXXX

Comment: Oh well, I guess we'll just have to burn Meta down. I'm planting the explosives and setting the timer for 10 minutes. Get out or go down with the ship!

Answer (score 6):

This is the **meta**-website. Specifically set up to deal with the **meta**-subjects.  At least until we launch meta-meta-stackoverflow.com ...
**EDIT:**
First of all the link you mentioned ([blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)) refers to stackoverflow.com, not **meta**.stackoverflow.com.
**meta**.stackoverflow.com was specifically created with the intention of supporting and administrating stackoverflow. The **meta**-tags you have shown above are necessary for the adequate response to each question by moderators, meta-users, and the devteam. The content of **meta**.stackoverflow is intended to cover **meta**-topics, without which, the site would not exist. Since **meta**-tags help the process, they are still here

Comment: meta already has the meta-meta tag. So we're recursively meta.

Comment: @Jon B but what about the meta-meta-meta tag?

Comment: Still, even if this is meta site, the questions have a content, (the content would be meta on SO, but it is not meta here). The widely used tags I have listed as examples are clearly meta here, as they are not related to the content of the question, they describe the nature of the question instead, and therefore are meta-tags here and should be discouraged.

As probably most people can see those meta tags are very useful, this means meta-tags server some useful role and eradicating them completely is not very wise.

QED

Comment: @Suma The flaw in this logic is that the nature of the Meta site is different than the corresponding parent site. For example, discussion questions are not a good idea on the parent site, but on the Meta it's a very useful aspect of the process and quite encouraged. Yes, we use the same Q&A engine to support the Meta, but that doesn't make the same set of rules that apply on the parent site have to apply to the Meta site, nor vice versa.

Comment: @Suma: Nobody is talking about eradicating these tags from MSO.  As you said, they're "very useful" here.  However, meta tags on the main sites aren't at all useful.  In fact, a lot of them encouraged "bad behavior" like posting subjective questions and expecting the `[subjective]` tag to work as a shield from closing, or editing the `[beginner]` tag into a question that was posted by someone you don't know.

Comment: @James, I don't think you edited enough meta into the answer :p

Comment: @Andy E's Head my 'ctrl-b' fingers hurt...

Comment: @Suma also, i would appreciate it if you did not use QED when your argument does not make sense logically.

Comment: Slightly off topic, and it may just be me, but is the phrase "meta-tags" being used wrongly? [Meta-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta) is a pompous prefix used to indicate a concept which is an abstraction from another concept. `Meta-stackoverflow` is a Q&A site for questions about a Q&A site. `Metaprogramming` is writing computer programs that write other programs. A `metacompiler` is a compiler that creates compilers. So logically `meta-tags` should be "tags that apply to tags", not "a particular subset of tags". Unless we're redefining `meta-` and it now means something like "subjective"?